# Can I use Flink state to perform join?

Tags: join, apache-flink

I am evaluating Apache Flink for stream processing as a replacement/complement of Apache Spark. One of the tasks we are usually solving with Spark is data enrichment.

I.e, I have stream of data from IoT sensors with sensor ID and I have set of sensors metadata. I want to transform input stream to stream of sensor measure+sensor metadata.

In Spark I can join DStream with RDD.

```scala
case calss SensorValue(sensorId: Long, ...)
case class SensorMetadata(sensorId: Long, ...)
val sensorInput: DStream[SensorValue] = readEventsFromKafka()
val staticMetadata: RDD[(Long, SensorMetadata)] =
  spark.read.json(...).as[SensorMetadata]
 .map {s => (s.sensorId, s)}.rdd
val joined: DStream[(SensorValue, SensorMetadata)] = 
  sensorInput.map{s => (s.sensorId, s)}.transform { rdd: RDD[SensorValue] => 
  rdd.join(staticMetadata)
     .map { case (_, (s, m)) => (s, m) } // Get rid of nested tuple
}
```

Can I do same trick with Apache Flink? I see no direct API on this. Only idea I have is to use stateful transformation - I can merge metadata and sensor events in a single stream and use Flink state storage to store metadata (pseudocode):

```scala
val sensorInput: DataStream[SensorValue] = readEventsFromKafka()
val statisMetadata: DataStream[SensorMetadata] = readMetadataFromJson()
val result: DataStream[(SensorValue, SensorMetadata)] =
  sensorInput.keyBy("sensorId")
 .connect(staticMetadata.keyBy("sensorId"))
 .flatMap {new RichCoFlatMapFunction() {
   private val ValueState<SensorMetadata> md = _;
   override def open = ??? // initiate value state
   def flatMap1(s: SensorEvent, s: Collector(SensorEvent, SensorMetadata)) = 
      collector.collect(s, md.value) 
   def flatMap2(s: SensorMetadata, s: Collector[(SensorEvent, SensorMetadata)]) = 
   md.update(s)  
 }}
```

Is this correct approach? Can I use under larger scale, when metadata doesn't fit on one machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `CoFlatMapFunction` to join is a common approach. However, it has one significant drawback. The function is called whenever a tuple of either input arrives and you cannot control which input to consume first. So in the beginning, you will have to handle sensor events when the metadata has not been completely read. One approach is to buffer all events of one input until the other input is consumed. On the other hand, the `CoFlatMapFunction` approach has the benefit that you can dynamically update the metadata. In your code example, both inputs are keyed on the join key. That means that the input is partitioned and each taskslot is processing a different key set. Hence, your metadata can be larger than what a machine can handle (if you configure the RocksDB state backend the state can be persisted to disk, so you are not even bound by the size of the memory).

If you require that all metadata must be present when the job starts and if the metadata is static (it does not change) and is small enough to fit into one machine, you can also use a regular `FlatMapFunction` and load the metadata in the `open()` method from a file. In contrast to your approach, this would be a broadcast join, where each taskslot has the complete metadata in memory. Besides having all metadata available when the event data is consumed, the approach has the benefit that you do not need to shuffle the event data because it can be joined on any machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Only thing that is left unclear for me - how can I 'buffer' input? Can you please give me some keywords to search?

Comment: You could create a second keyed state object into which you append event records until the corresponding metadata event arrived. When this happens, you join and emit all events, clear the event state and insert the metadata event into the metadata state.